# Python function is getting called four times

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting an issue where my function `start_backup_jobs()` running four times and at this point I am not able to fix that.

Here are the few insight on the functions inside the script:

1. The function `get_volume_arns()` fetches the amazon resource names(ARNs) of all amazon FSxN(NetApp ONTAP) file systems.
2. The Second function `get_filtered_volumes_and_tags()` to filters the specific tags and return the ARN of  FSxN Volumes along with their tag key and value.
3. Another function which is running four times IE `start_backup_jobs()` creates the backup jobs for the FSxN  Volumes, using the given backup vault, IAM role, and the bckp_client object which returns a list of pairs(`job_pairs`) containing the backup job ID and ARN.
4. Another function `get_backup_status_and_jobs()` which fetches the backup job_ids and the Job Status and that returns a pair of job_ids and backup status.
5. Another function IE `store_backup_job_id_and_arn()` that stores the backup job_ids, job_arn, a timestamp, and the jos status in the DynamoDB table.

At Last, function `list_backup_status()` lists the `Backup ID` and `Status` which is  initiated backup jobs.

### Below is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto3
import time
import datetime
from prettytable import PrettyTable

bckp_client = boto3.client("backup", region_name="eu-west-1")
fsx_client = boto3.client("fsx", region_name="eu-west-1")
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1')


def get_volume_arns():
    volume_arns = []
    fsx_volumes_response = fsx_client.describe_volumes()
    for volume in fsx_volumes_response["Volumes"]:
        volume_arns.append(volume["ResourceARN"])
    return volume_arns


def get_filtered_volumes_and_tags():
    filtered_volume_arns = []
    keys = []
    values = []
    for volume_arn in get_volume_arns():
        tags = fsx_client.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceARN=volume_arn)
        for tag in tags["Tags"]:
            if str(tag).split("'")[3] == "test" and str(tag).split("'")[7] == "demo_tag":
                filtered_volume_arns.append(volume_arn)
                keys.append(str(tag).split("'")[3])
                values.append(str(tag).split("'")[7])
    table = PrettyTable(["Filtered Volume ARN", "Key", "Value"])
    for i in range(len(filtered_volume_arns)):
        table.add_row([filtered_volume_arns[i], keys[i], values[i]])
    print(table)
    return filtered_volume_arns


def start_backup_jobs():
    job_ids = []
    job_arns = []
    vol_arns = get_filtered_volumes_and_tags()
    iam_role="testrole"
    vault_name="storage-backup-vault"

    for vol_arn in vol_arns:
        response = bckp_client.start_backup_job(
            BackupVaultName=vault_name,
            ResourceArn=vol_arn,
            IamRoleArn=iam_role,
        )
        job_ids.append(response['BackupJobId'])
        job_arns.append(vol_arn)
        job_pairs = [(job_ids[i], job_arns[i]) for i in range(len(job_ids))]
    return job_pairs

jobs = start_backup_jobs()


def get_backup_status_and_jobs():
    backup_job_ids = []
    backup_status = []
    response = bckp_client.list_backup_jobs()
    for job in response["BackupJobs"]:
        backup_job_ids.append(job["BackupJobId"])
        backup_status.append(job["State"])
    return backup_job_ids, backup_status

status_pairs = get_backup_status_and_jobs()

def store_backup_job_id_and_arn(job_id, job_arn, job_state):
    jobs = start_backup_jobs()
    time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    table_name = "Demo-BackupJobTable"
    table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
    table.put_item(
        Item={
            'BackupJobId': job_id,
            'BackupJobArn': job_arn,
            'TimeStamp': time_stamp,
            'Job_status': job_state
        }
    )
for (job_id, job_arn), job_state in zip(jobs, status_pairs[1]):
    print(f"Creating database entry for BackupJobId: {job_id}")
    store_backup_job_id_and_arn(job_id, job_arn, job_state)


def list_backup_status():
    job_pairs = start_backup_jobs()
    job_ids = [pair[0] for pair in job_pairs]
    backup_job_ids, backup_status = get_backup_status_and_jobs()
    list_pairs = [(backup_job_ids[i], backup_status[i]) for i in range(len(backup_job_ids)) if backup_job_ids[i] in job_ids]
    table = PrettyTable(["Backup ID", "Status"])
    for backup_id, state in list_pairs:
        table.add_row([backup_id, state])
    print(table)
list_backup_status()
```

### Current Result output:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
|                                  Filtered Volume ARN                                   | Key  |  Value   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
| arn:aws:fsx:eu-west-1:<account_number>:volume/<filesystem_id>/fsvol-12345678910111111 | test | demo_tag |
| arn:aws:fsx:eu-west-1:<account_number>:volume/<filesystem_id>/fsvol-12345678920222222 | test | demo_tag |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
Creating database entry for BackupJobId: 117d76a9-11a7-177g-9efc-e5e280aca2d0
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
|                                  Filtered Volume ARN                                   | Key  |  Value   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
| arn:aws:fsx:eu-west-1:<account_number>:volume/<filesystem_id>/fsvol-12345678910111111 | test | demo_tag |
| arn:aws:fsx:eu-west-1:<account_number>:volume/<filesystem_id>/fsvol-12345678920222222 | test | demo_tag |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
Creating database entry for BackupJobId: 3bb2c2tc-3f37-1ab5-a327-2t9t8c56dcda
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
|                                  Filtered Volume ARN                                   | Key  |  Value   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
| arn:aws:fsx:eu-west-1:<account_number>:volume/<filesystem_id>/fsvol-12345678910111111 | test | demo_tag |
| arn:aws:fsx:eu-west-1:<account_number>:volume/<filesystem_id>/fsvol-12345678920222222 | test | demo_tag |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
|                                  Filtered Volume ARN                                   | Key  |  Value   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
| arn:aws:fsx:eu-west-1:<account_number>:volume/<filesystem_id>/fsvol-12345678910111111 | test | demo_tag |
| arn:aws:fsx:eu-west-1:<account_number>:volume/<filesystem_id>/fsvol-12345678920222222 | test | demo_tag |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+
+--------------------------------------+---------+
|              Backup ID               |  Status |
+--------------------------------------+---------+
| 12a3e263-a111-5c5c-1112-7t9dc40e5544 | CREATED |
| 4h123h7b-177g-4ae5-9b8b-a7cc6b52e123 | CREATED |
+--------------------------------------+---------+
```

There are only two volumes with the filtered tags, So ideally it should create two backup Jobs in the AWS as follows, while in the results it only shows one as follows but creating similar 4 sets in the background.

```
+--------------------------------------+---------+
|              Backup ID               |  Status |
+--------------------------------------+---------+
| 12a3e263-a111-5c5c-1112-7t9dc40e5544 | CREATED |
| 4h123h7b-177g-4ae5-9b8b-a7cc6b52e123 | CREATED |
+--------------------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: You call the function `start_backup_jobs` three times in your code, once in a loop, leading to four calls.  What do you want to fix?

Comment: @AnonCoward,  thanks for your comment. I want to fix it to run once only, due to my limited knowledge on python at this point am not able to fix that, i want `start_backup_jobs` to be called once however, i require `job_pairs` to be used in another function to monitor the `backupID and ARN`.

Comment: I don't think the issue here is your Python knowledge. At a high level, your task seems to be get a list of the volumes of interest e.g. `vols = get_volumes_filtered(sometags)` and then start a backup for each volume e.g. `results = [start_backup_jobs(vol) for vol in vols]`.

Comment: @jarmod, thanks for the comment, still i am unable to fix the issue.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

I have just modified the code a bit and at least its running only once. I am posting it here for posterity until a very well answer received or suggested.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto3
import time
import datetime
from prettytable import PrettyTable

bckp_client = boto3.client("backup", region_name="eu-west-1")
fsx_client = boto3.client("fsx", region_name="eu-west-1")
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1')

def backup_jobi_notifier():
    print(f"Starting the archiving Job, Please don't interrupt .....")
backup_jobi_notifier()

def create_table():
    try:
        table_name = 'Demo-BackupJobTable'
        table = dynamodb.create_table(
            TableName=table_name,
            KeySchema=[
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'BackupJobId',
                    'KeyType': 'HASH'
                },
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'BackupJobArn',
                    'KeyType': 'RANGE'
                }
            ],
            AttributeDefinitions=[
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'BackupJobId',
                    'AttributeType': 'S'
                },
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'BackupJobArn',
                    'AttributeType': 'S'
                }
            ],
            ProvisionedThroughput={
                'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
                'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
            }
        )
        print(f"Table '{table_name}' created successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        if "ResourceInUseException" in str(e):
            print(f"Table '{table_name}' already exists.")
        else:
           print(f"Error creating table '{table_name}' .")
           print(e)
create_table()


def get_volume_arns():
    volume_arns = []
    fsx_volumes_response = fsx_client.describe_volumes()
    for volume in fsx_volumes_response["Volumes"]:
        volume_arns.append(volume["ResourceARN"])
    return volume_arns


def get_filtered_volumes_and_tags():
    filtered_volume_arns = []
    keys = []
    values = []
    for volume_arn in get_volume_arns():
        tags = fsx_client.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceARN=volume_arn)
        for tag in tags["Tags"]:
            if str(tag).split("'")[3] == "test" and str(tag).split("'")[7] == "demo_tag":
                filtered_volume_arns.append(volume_arn)
                keys.append(str(tag).split("'")[3])
                values.append(str(tag).split("'")[7])
    table = PrettyTable(["Filtered Volume ARN", "Key", "Value"])
    for i in range(len(filtered_volume_arns)):
        table.add_row([filtered_volume_arns[i], keys[i], values[i]])
    print(table)
    return filtered_volume_arns


def start_backup_jobs():
    try:
        job_ids = []
        job_arns = []
        vol_arns = get_filtered_volumes_and_tags()
        iam_role="testrole"
        vault_name="storage-backup-vault"

        for vol_arn in vol_arns:
            response = bckp_client.start_backup_job(
                BackupVaultName=vault_name,
                ResourceArn=vol_arn,
                IamRoleArn=iam_role,
            )
            job_ids.append(response['BackupJobId'])
            job_arns.append(vol_arn)
        return dict(zip(job_ids, job_arns))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error starting backup jobs: {e}")
        return {}


def get_backup_status_and_jobs():
    try:
        backup_job_ids = []
        backup_status = []
        response = bckp_client.list_backup_jobs()
        for job in response["BackupJobs"]:
            backup_job_ids.append(job["BackupJobId"])
            backup_status.append(job["State"])
        return dict(zip(backup_job_ids, backup_status))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting backup job status: {e}")
        return {}


def store_backup_job_id_and_arn(job_id, job_arn, job_state):
    try:
        time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        table_name = "Demo-BackupJobTable"
        table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
        table.put_item(
            Item={
                'BackupJobId': job_id,
                'BackupJobArn': job_arn,
                'TimeStamp': time_stamp,
                'Job_status': job_state
            }
        )
        print(f"Creating database entry for BackupJobId: {job_id}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error storing backup job data: {e}")


def list_backup_status():
    try:
        job_pairs = start_backup_jobs()
        job_ids = job_pairs.keys()
        backup_status = get_backup_status_and_jobs()
        table = PrettyTable(["Backup ID", "Status"])
        for backup_id in job_ids:
            if backup_id in backup_status:
                state = backup_status[backup_id]
                job_arn = job_pairs[backup_id]
                table.add_row([backup_id, state])
                store_backup_job_id_and_arn(backup_id, job_arn, state)
        print(table)
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred: ", e)

list_backup_status()
```

Comment: Does this code do what you want? If not, can you share what's wrong with it?

Comment: @jarmod, Thanks again for looking into this, Yes it does the what i want from it now, I was thinking in case i want the `return dict(zip(job_ids, job_arns))` from the function `start_backup_jobs` into multiple other function without running the start_backup_job again that will e more flexible.